# Need help using integration on a differential equation

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck.  I haven't done any calculus in over a year and cannot figure out how to solve this.  I need to integrate and rearrange this equation
\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{dt} = -kN
\end{align}

into this equation
\begin{align}
\log N = -kt + \log N_0
\end{align}

Comment: Use `\log N` to produce $\log N$. It looks much better than $log N$. [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for other useful tips and tricks about the use of latex/Mathjax on this site.

Answer (score 3):

You should know that $\int \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \log{x}+C$. We have
$$ \int -k \, dt = \int \frac{1}{N}\frac{dN}{dt} \, dt = \int \frac{dN}{N} = \log{N}+C, $$
the left-hand side is just $-kt$ since $k$ is constant, and hence
$$ \log{N} = -kt + \log{N_0}, $$
where $N_0$ is the value of the function $N$ at $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Divide both parts of the equation by $N$ and then integrate them.

$$\frac{dN}{N} \to \ln(N) + \text{const}$$

$$k\cdot dt \to k\cdot t$$

Comment: I was typing from phone

Answer (score 0):

${\frac{dN}{dt}} = -kN$ thus $\int {\frac{dN}{N}}=\int -k dt$ thus $\log N = -kt + c$